# How can I make an interactive SSH Terminal inside React?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

What I'm trying to do is to make an interactive Web-SSH Terminal which auto-connects to a specified server using keybased-auth.

I found some projects which do exactly that: https://github.com/huashengdun/webssh

The problem is that I cannot directly include that in my existing React project as everything I found runs on an own "server instance" and using iframes is not really an option. I also had a look at [ssh2](https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2) but that really only is an ssh client, not an interactive terminal as far as I see. Is there any similiar project available like webssh which I can directly implement as a npm-dependency and use it directly in my code? Or how can I make an interactive terminal else?

Comment: Could you find any solution?

Comment: Sadly not, I gave up and discarded the idea. You can use an iframe and include sshwifty and already pass all the necessary options, but that is not ideal.

Answer (score 1):

You could try
[daffi-terminals](https://pypi.org/project/daffi-terminals/)

The JavaScript code consists of just 200 lines, making it straightforward to migrate to React. However, it does not utilize the ssh API.